# Get a spring boot configurable application context without running the server

Tags: spring

For a spring boot application, I can get a `ConfigurableApplicationContext` using:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = 
            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, this also launches a server. I need to perform some instrumentation on the spring-context setup, and would like an instance of `ApplicationContext`, but without launching the server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot launches a server only if `spring-boot-starter-web` is present on the classpath. If you skip that and include only the dependencies that you need for your task (e.g. jdbc, jpa, batch) the program will be a simple console application and it will not launch a web server.